# How to mock HttpContext.Current.Items with NUnit and Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nunit, rhino-mocks

I'm using `NUnit` and `RhinoMocks` for unit testing on the (WebApi) project.

There is a method I'm trying to write test for, which is supposed to add an item to HttpContext.Current.Items.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("RequestGUID", Guid.NewGuid());
    base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
}
```

I have no idea how can I make `HttpContext.Current.Items` available to the method when ran from within a test method. How can I achieve this?

Also, how can I check if the item has been added (what kind of assertion can/should I use)

Comment: Are you able to refactor that code? It is tightly coupled to `HttpContext` which makes it very difficult to test and should be avoided.

Comment: Yes I am. What do you suggest? I simply wrap the HttpContext in a dummy/empty class, or something else?

Comment: What version of asp.net is this. MVC5?, WEB API 2? Going to need more context as to where that method is from

Comment: It's not, it's actually my custom filter attribute that inherits from ActionFilterAttribute class. I tried accessing through actionContext but could not figure it out. The project is WebAPI 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to refactor your code\use `RhinoMocks` at all for testing it.

Your UT should be similar to the following example:

```
[Test]
public void New_GUID_should_be_added_when_OnActionExecuting_is_executing()
{
    //arrange section:
    const string REQUEST_GUID_FIELD_NAME = "RequestGUID";

    var httpContext = new HttpContext(
        new HttpRequest("", "http://google.com", ""),
        new HttpResponse(new StringWriter())
    );

    HttpContext.Current = httpContext;

    //act:
    target.OnActionExecuting(new HttpActionContext());

    //assert section:
    Assert.IsTrue(HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(REQUEST_GUID_FIELD_NAME));
    var g = HttpContext.Current.Items[REQUEST_GUID_FIELD_NAME] as Guid?;
    if (g == null)
    {
        Assert.Fail(REQUEST_GUID_FIELD_NAME + 
                    " is not a GUID, it is :: {0}", 
                    HttpContext.Current.Items[REQUEST_GUID_FIELD_NAME]);
    }
    Assert.AreNotEqual(Guid.Empty, g.Value);
}
```

BTW, you can split this test to 2:

1. verifies that the RequestGUID is being populated with a GUID
2. verifies that the GUID is not `Guid.Empty`

Comment: This worked like a charm. No need for mocking at all. Great. Thanks!

Comment: This should probably be a separate question. But how would I go about mocking HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Request.Context :) ?

Comment: @Eedoh just to be honest I'm no longer in the .net world for more then 2 years... So I think it will be much better for you to post a new question... I saw the other answer which was completely wrong so I had to add an answer.... Otherwise I'd vote up and continue....

Comment: I will. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Eedoh, You welcome! I have a question, why do you need the `.Request.Context` suffix? Isn't that `HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()` return the same object?, P.M, send me the link of the new question, maybe in the rest of the week I'll have some free time, then I'll open a windows VM and find a solution...

Comment: It is, I probably "went with the flow" using IntelliSense and just copied and pasted... Here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45305608/how-to-mock-httpcontext-current-getowincontext-request-context-with-nunit-and