# How to mock HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext() with Nunit and RhinoMocks?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, owin, rhino-mocks

Compared to [my last question on Mocking the HttpContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239728/how-to-mock-httpcontext-current-items-with-nunit-and-rhino-mocks), I had to change the method being tested to

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Set("RequestGUID", NewId.NextGuid());
    base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
}
```

Now I need to figure out how to mock the 
`HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()`,
So I could write a stub for the `Set()` method, or generally being able to test this particular line. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have read [this article](http://www.juliencorioland.net/archives/using-owin-to-test-your-web-api-controllers#.WXy2-8cjGM8), but in your case, I think that doing such a thing would be an overkill..

Since `GetOwinContext()` return an interface all you have to do is to separate this call from the method, doing such a thing has 2 problems:

1. The method under test(`OnActionExecuting()` is owned by an attribute class.
2. `GetOwinContext()` is a static method.

The best 2 solutions that I can offer you is:

1. Use code waving tool like MsFakes, Typemock Isolator and etc, instead of proxy based tool like RhinoMocks.
2. Extract `GetOwinContext()` to a virtual method and then use PartialMock technique(This technique is usually in use for abstract classes):

Let's say that `MyCustonAttributte` is your attribute:

```
public class MyCustonAttributte : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        GetOwinContext().Set("RequestGUID", Guid.NewGuid());
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }

    public virtual IOwinContext GetOwinContext()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext();
    }
}
```

Then your UT will be:

```
[Test]
public void New_GUID_should_be_added_when_OnActionExecuting_is_executing()
{
    //arrange section:
    const string REQUEST_GUID_FIELD_NAME = "RequestGUID";
    var owinContext = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IOwinContext>();

    var target = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<MyCustonAttributte>();

    target.Stub(x => x.GetOwinContext())
        .Return(owinContext);

    //act:
    target.OnActionExecuting(new HttpActionContext());

    //assert section:
    owinContext.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Set(Arg<string>.Is.Equal(REQUEST_GUID_FIELD_NAME),
        Arg<Guid>.Is.NotEqual(Guid.Empty)));
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. GUID being added to the collection is the only thing I had/wanted to test for anyway... Thanks a million.